# Número dentro de um arquivo pode ser o número dentro do time.sleep?

Tags: python

É possível que um número dentro de um arquivo possa ser o número de segundos do time.sleep()?
Exemplo:

```
time.sleep(temp)
#código de leitura e salvamento de dados incluído
```

Código completo:

```
   #============<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>============================#
def ler():                                                                    #
    with open('maquina virtual 1ªversão-texto inicial.txt', 'r') as f:        #
        linhas = f.readlines()                                                #
        return linhas                                                         #
    f.close()                                                                 #
                                                                              #
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                    #
    dados = ler()                                                             #
    dados = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in dados)  #
#============<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>============================#
                                                                              #
def reading():                                                                #
    with open('Password VM.txt', 'r') as f:                                   #
        linhas = f.readlines()                                                #
        return linhas                                                         #
    f.close()                                                                 #
                                                                              #
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                    # 
    tic = reading()                                                           #                                        
    tic = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in tic)      #
#==========<<<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>>>==========================# 
                                                                              #
def ler_tempo_boot():                                                         #
    with open('Tempo de boot.txt', 'r') as f:                                 #
        linhas = f.readlines()                                                 #
        return linhas                                                         #
    f.close()                                                                 #
                                                                              #
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                    #
    temp = ler_tempo_boot()                                                   #
    temp = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in temp)    #
#==========<<<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>>>==========================# 

#============<<<código de salvação de dados>>>==========================#
def guardarAlteracao(dado):                                             #
    with open('maquina virtual 1ªversão-texto inicial.txt', 'r+') as f: #
        f.write(dado)                                                   #
    f.close()                                                           #
#============<<<código de salvação de dados>>>==========================#
def guardarPasswordvm(info):                                            #
    with open('Password VM.txt', 'r+') as f:                            #
        f.write(info)                                                   #
    f.close()                                                           #
#============<<<código de salvação de dados>>>==========================#
def guardarTempoBoot(times):                                            #
    with open('Tempo de boot.txt', 'r+') as f:                          #
        f.write(times)                                                  #
    f.close()                                                           #
#============<<<código de salvação de dados>>>==========================#

def palavra_passe_vm():
    if(len(tic) > 0):
        passwordvm = raw_input("Palavra-passe:")
        if passwordvm == (str(tic)) :
            print "Palavra-passe correta."
        else:
            print "Palavra-passe incorreta."
            palavra_passe_vm()

#função que inicia a máquina virtual (função que coopera com a função bios()-> se esta tiver sido indevidamente alterada pelo usuário, esta impede o arranque do SO
def arranque():
    palavra_passe_vm()
    if (len(dados) == 0):
        print "Bem vindo à máquina virtual. Prima ENTER para iniciar o SO ou B para aceder ao menu da BIOS setup utility."
    else:
        print dados
    machine = raw_input("")
    if machine == "B".upper():
        print "A iniciar o BIOS..."
        import time
        time.sleep(7)         
    elif machine == "":
        import time
        if temp >=20:
            time.sleep(int(temp))
            powerbit()
        else:
            time.sleep(30)
    else:
        arranque()
arranque()

#função principal(1ª)--> bios:
def bios():
    print "------------------ \n"
    print "BIOS setup utility \n"
    print "------------------"
    opcao =raw_input("Está no menu da BIOS. Escolha o que pretende aceder: Informações do sistema(a), Data(b), Avançadas(c), Configurações do SO(d) (escreva quit para voltar ao menu e back se quiser voltar ao menu principal da BIOS) \n")
    if opcao == "Informações do sistema" or opcao == "a".lower():
        print "--------------"
        print "Maquina virtual"
        print "--------------"
        print "Versão: 1.0v 32bit \n Data da criação: 07/06/14 \n Compatível com Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Unix, Linux, Ubuntu e Mac OS"
        print "Todos os direitos reservados © 2014"
        rebobinar = raw_input("")
        if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
            bios()
        else:
            bios()
    elif opcao == "Data" or opcao == "b".lower():
        print "--------------"
        print "Data"
        print "--------------"
        print "Sistema Operativo(simulado): BITsky one® \nInterface: Literal (e GUI nas próximas atualizações) \nLinguagem de programação predefinida: Python"
        import win32api
        path = "C:/"
        info = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(path)
        print( "Número da série do disco rígido: = %d" % info[1] )
        rebobinar = raw_input("")
        if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
            bios()
        else:
            bios()
    elif opcao == "Avançadas" or opcao == "c".lower():
        print "--------------"
        print "Avançadas"
        print "--------------"
        configurar = raw_input("Para configurar as defenições da máquina virtual, escreva a password bitwise para aceder: \n")
        if configurar == "0b10b100b110b100":
            print "As opções disponíveis são: \nAlterar a forma de inicialização(a), \nDesinstalar SO(b), \nCriar permissões especiais para a VM(c), \nVer código fonte da VM(d)"
            avanced = raw_input("")
            if avanced == "Alterar a forma de inicialização" or avanced == "a".lower():
                alterar = raw_input("O que deseja alterar: \nApresentação inicial da VM(a), \nApresentar código de arranque(b)(aviso: qualquer alteração incorreta destes pode instabilizar a VM)?")
                if alterar == "Apresentação inicial da VM" or alterar == "a".lower():
                    imprima = raw_input("Digite o texto que pretende que o programa imprima no início (sugestão: refira os nomes das teclas que iniciam o SO(ENTER) ou o menu da BIOS(B)):")
                    save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                    if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                        guardarAlteracao(imprima)
                    rebobinar = raw_input("")
                    if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                        bios()
                elif alterar == "Apresentar código de arranque" or alterar == "b".lower():
                    #código ainda não concluído
                    if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                        bios()
                    else:
                        bios()
                else:
                    bios()
            elif avanced == "Desinstalar SO" or avanced == "b".lower():
                deletar_so = raw_input("Tem mesmo a certeza (atenção: depois não pode restaurar e pode perder dados)?)")
                if deletar_so == "sim" or deletar_so == "yes":
                        print "A desinstalar o SO..."
                        import time
                        time.sleep(20)
                    #função bitsky_one--> deletar
                        print "SO desinstalado."
                else:
                    bios()
            elif avanced == "Criar permissões especiais para a VM" or avanced == "c".lower():
                passe = raw_input("Escreve uma password nova:")
                save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                    guardarPasswordvm(passe)
                rebobinar = raw_input("")
                if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                    bios()
                else:
                    bios()
            else:
                bios()
        else:
           bios()
    elif opcao == "quit" or opcao == "Q".upper():
        arranque()
    elif opcao == "Configurações do SO" or opcao == "d".lower():
        alteracao = raw_input("As opções disponíveis são: \nModificar o tempo de boot do SO(a) \nFormatar SO(b)")
        if alteracao == "Modificar o tempo de boot do SO" or alteracao == "a":
            alterar_boot = raw_input("Insira o tempo que deseja que o SO demore a iniciar:\n")
            try:
                alterar_boot = int(alterar_boot)
            except ValueError:
                print "Digite um número inteiro positivo maior ou igual a 20!"
                bios()
            if alterar_boot >= 20:
                print "Valor de tempo suportado."
            else:
                bios()
                save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                    guardarTempoBoot(alterar_boot)
    else:
        bios()
bios()
#from Tkinter import *
#import win32api
#print win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
```

Desculpem se comentei pouco o código e a função powerbit ainda não foi criada.

Comment: Esses comentários envolvendo o código são padrão em Python?

Comment: Como assim? Eu penso que sim.

Comment: Só por curiosidade mesmo, eu nunca mexi com Python e nunca tinha visto esse tipo de comentário "envolvendo" o código. :)

Comment: Fui eu que envolvi o código: foi só meter o símbolo de comentário nas linhas e fica mais fácil de identificar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No código apresentado por você a função `ler_tempo_boot()` retorna a duração em segundos a ser utilizado no `time.sleep()`.

```py
try:
   temp = int(ler_tempo_boot())
   time.sleep(temp)
except ValueError:
   # Não conseguiu ler o número
```

Comment: Deu este erro: 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'